# R ggplot2: Display Ribbon Area on Graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to display the area of a ribbon on my graph using ggplot2. Specifically, I've used this code to produce the following graph:

```
ggplot(data=mean_frame, mapping=aes(x=Percent, y=Mean)) +
   geom_smooth(method="loess", se = F) +
   geom_ribbon(alpha = 0.3,
              aes(fill = Percent < 23, ymin = 0, ymax = predict(loess(Mean ~ Percent)))) +
   scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "red"), name = "fill") +
   geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype="dashed", color = "black") + ylab("") + xlab("") +
   coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-.1, .6)) + 
    guides(fill=FALSE) +
   annotate('text', x = 10, y = .05, label =  "Area = ???",  col = 'red', size = 6) +
   annotate('text', x = 85, y = -.03, label =  "Area = ???",  size = 6, col = 'springgreen4')
```

[image]

On the graph, I want to replace the question marks with the area of the red shaded area and the area of the green shaded area. How can I access & display the size of these shaded areas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what you want to do is to integrate the function to calculate the **area under the curve** (*auc*).

There is a package which helps you with that. Since you did not share a `reprex`, I show the principle with some fake data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(flux) # for function auc
library(dplyr)
library(glue)

d <- tibble(x = seq(1, 3, length.out = 100), 
            y = 1 / x - .5,
            ind = if_else(y < 0, "neg", "pos"))
sum_stat <- d %>%
  group_by(ind) %>%
  summarise(auc = auc(x, y),
            y   = y[which.min((x - mean(x)) ^ 2)] / 2,
            x   = mean(x)) %>%
  mutate(text = glue("Area = {round(abs(auc), 2)}"))

ggplot(d, aes(x, y, fill = ind))+ 
   geom_area() +
   geom_label(aes(label = text), fill = "white", data = sum_stat)
```

[image: Area under the curve]

In this toy example I plotted the function `f(x) = 1 / x - .5`. The area under the curve is the integral of this function between `1` and `2` for the positive part, and `2` and `3` for the negative part. You can do your math to figure that the integral of `f(x)` equals `F(x) = log(x) - .5 * x`, and `F(2) - F(1) = 0.1931472` and `|F(3) - F(2)| =  0.09453489`. If your math is a bit rusty, you could also ask `R` to do the integration for you and you will find the same results:

```
integrate(function(x) 1 / x - .5, 1, 2)
# 0.1931472 with absolute error < 2.1e-15
integrate(function(x) 1 / x - .5, 2, 3)
# -0.09453489 with absolute error < 1e-15
```